# Stop Body Scrolling under a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So My situation is this, I have a lot of divs... A LOT (over 300) and im using them as part of an interactive background. EDIT:(they all have the same class btw)

The Problem? 
Since on mobile I need more divs to fill the page than on desktop, I have too many divs on desktop, meaning you can scroll wayyyyyy more than I want to. 
How can I have it so Divs Below a certain point are deleted or (more usefully) how to stop scrolling after a certain amount of pixels.

I literally have no idea how to do this, I've tried experimenting with margins, padding, overflow, position: fixed; but I haven't found a solution so don't pester my "lack of effort" 
(some of my accounts have been blocked because I had no legitimate idea what to do and you "cool kids" decided to downvote me enough to get blocked (thanks for that!))

Anyway enough blabbing. Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Can you please put your code here or give some link so can I identify.

Comment: "How can I have it so Divs Below a certain point are deleted or (more usefully) how to stop scrolling after a certain amount of pixels." I think i was quite clear

Comment: Don't worry though, this has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your divs inside a container div and use this css

```
.container{
   max-height:900px; // Set this value to the no of pixel you want to scroll
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

I have set the `max-height` to `900px` cause i want to show only 9 div each div is off height `100px`.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  max-height: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  
  <!--You cant scroll after that-->
  
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things for this:

1. Wrap all your content in a div and set height to it and overflow-y: hidden.

`.wrapper{
   height: 1000px; overflow-y: hidden
 }`

2. With CSS you can hide the elements after certain number. Like if you want to hide all div after 100

`.container .className:nth-child(n+101) {
    display: none;
  }`

This will hide all the divs after 100.

Comment: This Also works! But I'm going to mark the other as correct because they replied first

Comment: Cool you can +1 if you like the answer